# get all posts associated with a custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Looks like the advanced tax query options in WordPress does not allow the following query:

> Get me the most recent posts but only those posts that have at least
>   one term under the taxonomy I'm interested in ( here the key thing is
>   "any term" under that taxonomy would be OK to qualify that post to be
>   part of the results )

The taxonomy query samples I've seen so far does things like this

> Get me the most recent posts but only those posts that have term A and term B of that taxonomy.  ( Here, the limiting thing is that I must specify the terms I want and I do not seem to have an option to say, "all terms" or "any term"

Am I correct in saying that what I want is not possible with the current query params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with the `tax_query` parameter since version 4.1, use `EXISTS` as the operator parameter in your tax query.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mytax',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hey Milo, what if you need to combine this with another term; say category='featured' , how would the $args be changing? We need the relation AND, there. Right?